# wchar_t output with libc++

Tags: c++, clang++, libc++

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
    std::wcout << L"Həł£ō שøяļđ\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected with libstdc++ (both gcc and clang), but only prints the first character (which happens to be ASCII) with libc++. I'm using libcxx-0.0_p20140322 on Gentoo Linux.

Is this a known bug in libc++, or just me not knowing how to cook it?

Update 1. I have tried

```
std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

which all do the same thing.

Update 2. The wide string literal is here for simplicity. The same thing happens when the string is obtained in any other way (converted from UTF-8, read from binary file, ...)

Comment: Try adding `std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` at the beginning?

Comment: Note: it's not required for the compiler to support embedding those characters in our source (the *source character set* differs from the *execution character set*), and your locale setting is only a runtime thing, it does not affect how the compiler handles this string.  Try using a C++11 unicode string literal? (perhaps even specifying the characters via `\uNNNNN` codes)

Comment: standard C++ only has two known locales: the C locale and the user's default locale. another issue is that g++ of old only honored the C library's locale, IIRC. thus, Kerrek's advice to call `setlocale` (changing the C library's locale) might be just what's needed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Hm, I think `setlocale` doesn't "change the C locale", it just changes the current locale (but not as far as iostreams is concerned). The C locale is just called `"C"`, whereas `""` says to take the locale info from the envorinment.

Comment: @n.m.: Ah, that makes sense. You could have thrown `printf` with `%ls` into the mix for good measure...

Comment: @KerrekSB: "C library locale" != "C locale". the former is a descriptive term referring to the locale variable that `setlocale` maintains, the latter is a name of a specific locale value. ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to explicitly imbue the output stream with a locale, like so:

```
std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
```

This makes things work as expected. In fact, it is *required* by the standard:

> 27.5.3.3 ios_base functions

> ```
> locale getloc() const;
> ```

> 4 If no locale has been imbued, a copy of the global C++ locale, locale(), in effect at the time of construction.

So when `wcout` is constructed, it gets a copy of the initial locale imbued in it. The initial locale is "C". My incorrect assumption was that streams which have no locale explicitly imbued use the current global locale always (and not just at the time of construction). This assumption is totally unreasonable if one thinks about it a little.

June 2021 edit: So in theory just `imbue` should work, however in practice it doesn't in libstdc++. One needs to set the global locale for this to work, which is probably a libstdc++ bug. Imbuing works with other wide-character streams, but not with `std::wcout`.