# Locale support in libc++ and libstdc++

Tags: c++, utf-8, locale, libstdc++, libc++

Consider this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()    
{                     
   std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));  // 1
   std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));     // 2
   std::wcout << L"é\n";
}
```

If I build and run this on a Linux machine with either gcc or clang, using either libc++ or libstdc++, this program prints the expected accented character. If I comment out both line 1 and line 2, it doesn't, again as fully expected (the default locale is "C" with no Unicode support).

Now strange things happen.

If I comment out only line 1, it works with libc++ but stops working with libstdc++.

If I comment out only line 2, it works with libstdc++ but stops working with libc++.

I would expect that either line should have the desired effect. Am I wrong to expect that?

I'm running Gentoo Linux with gcc-11.1.0, clang-11.1.0 and libc++-11.1.0.

Comment: The standard does not promise anything about "en_US.UTF-8" so I am not asking how (non-)standard-conforming is this behaviour.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24567920/10147399) Q&A by you seems relevant.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili haha I forgot about it. So in theory imbue should be sufficient, but in practice for libstdc++ it is not working...

Comment: There should be a badge for that.